# How can I get a mysqldump file encoded in utf-8 for psql?

Tags: mysql, encoding, postgresql, mysqldump, utf-8

I am migrating some data from a MySql database (v5.1.44/MyISAM/collation=latin1_swedish_ci) to a PostgreSQL (v9.0.4/the one included in OSX Lion).

I'm using

```
$ mysqldump --compatible=postgresql > tmp.sql # output create/insert statements
$ psql --command='\i tmp.sql' # import to postgresql
```

However the import fails with the error `ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe97261` (This is in reference to accented letters).

The issue, I think, being that the exported file is not using utf-8.

The file that is exported shows the following file information

```
$ file tmp.sql
tmp.sql: Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with very long lines
```

**What's the easiest, *scriptable* way to get this file prepared in utf-8 for psql?**

This does not work:

```
$ iconv -f ASCII -t UTF-8 tmp.sql > out.sql
iconv: tmp.sql:18:59270: cannot convert
```

I've found that opening the file in `vim` and issuing `:set fenc=utf-8` does make the import run smoothly, but this has to be automated so I need to cut out this manual step.

Comment: Have you tried: mysqldump --default-character-set=charset_name?

Comment: @mastashake57, I had not tried that and adding --default-character-set=utf8 does indeed solve my issue. If you write that up as an answer I will accept it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
mysqldump --default-character-set=charset_name
```